Results from two testing methods are present in a single Assert after Console.Out manipulation
I am starting to learn programming and I am coding simple algorithmic exercises. I have overheard that coding Unit Tests is a good practice. However, I have encountered a problem with a feature I am new to. I wanted to catch the Console output and use it in an Assert.
This is the function I am testing:
        public static void MinMaxSum(List<int> arr)
        {
            long minSum = long.MaxValue;
            long maxSum = long.MinValue;
            long totalSum = default;
            int n = arr.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                totalSum += arr[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                long currentSum = totalSum - arr[i];
                if (currentSum > maxSum)
                {
                    maxSum = currentSum;
                }
                if (currentSum < minSum)
                {
                    minSum = currentSum;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(minSum + " " + maxSum);
        }

I am 99% sure that it gives good results because it has passed the tests on HackerRank and it is generally marked as solved. However, I wanted to add unit tests, as a good practice.
Those are two Test methods and the entire Test1.cs file that I have:
namespace LCMinMaxSumTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public sealed class Test1
    {
        private TextWriter originalOut = null!;
        private StringWriter sw = null!;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetOriginalConsoleOutput()
        {
            originalOut = Console.Out;
            sw = new StringWriter();
            Console.SetOut(sw);
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void RestoreOriginalConsoleOutput()
        {
            Console.SetOut(originalOut);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
            HCRNKMinMaxSum.Program.MinMaxSum(list);
            string expected = string.Format($"16 24{Environment.NewLine}");
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, sw.ToString());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            HCRNKMinMaxSum.Program.MinMaxSum(list);
            string expected = string.Format($"10 14{Environment.NewLine}");
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, sw.ToString());
        }
    }
}

The specific problem that I am encountering here is that the result of the first Assert is <10 14 16 24>, while the second Assert is empty - As if the results of the two were combined. Shamefully, I started asking Gemini 2 for the answer but it seems to not know it, all the solutions it was giving were leading to the same result. I am almost sure that the issue lies within the StringWriter and how it is handled, but I do not know how to fix it and Google has been of little help, and I could not find the solution on StackOverflow either. Is there something obvious I am missing? I have been sitting on it for 3 hours and I am out of ideas. I would be grateful if anyone could point out what I am doing wrong.
VS: 17.12.3
.NET: 9
I expect the Unit Test results to match the visual results that I got when testing the method on my own with custom data in Main(). The first version of those two methods, were that there was no [TestInitialize] and [TestCleanup] sections but the bodies of methods were wrapped in a using statement, like this:
using(StringWriter sw = new())
{
    //body of a function
}

From the functional standpoint, nothing changed, which leads me to the conclusion that the issue lies within the StringWriter and how Console output is handled. However, someone might as well prove me wrong.

I'm not familiar with this testing framework, but could it be that the tests are being run in parallel? Try adding [DoNotParallelize] to the [TestMethod]s.

The main important thing with unit tests is to have no hard coded external dependencies. You have Console as such a dependency in your code.

I wanted to catch the Console output and use it in an Assert - why not return the value instead and verify it?

@Sweeper Adding this attribute solved the problem. I will keep it in mind for the future! Thank you!

@SirRufo I will keep it in mind then. I will come up with a different method of testing void methods. Thank you for answering!

@flackoverstow My flaw - I am stubborn. Throughout the entirety of this predicament, I knew that I could do it by just restructuring the original tested function but something inside of me was sure that it must be possible to be done this way and even though I spent 3 hours on this, I think it was valuable for my future expertise. Thank you for your suggestions though!

One of the great things about writing tests, other than testing your code, is that they encourage you to write easily testable code, which in turn encourages you to write clean code. A function should do one thing, yours does two: calculates the numbers, and formats them and writes to the console. You found it hard to test. If you had a function for the calculation and another for the writing, you can test each more easily. It also helps when you refactor: if your tests fail, you know immediately if you've broken the calculation or broken the formatting/writing the result.

(continued) It also makes your function more useful: you can use it somewhere else that needs to use the answer rather than just outputting it.
